# how to read file with asyncSocket without knowing the file length?

Tags: ios, eof, asyncsocket

I have a file server(base on java), it's very simple, when the client connect to it, it will automatically send a file to the client. 
On the client side, it's also very simple, it just read from the socket until the read method return -1.
The implement code base on java looks like this:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int size = 0;

while((size = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG,"we have data in");
    ...
}
```

But now I want to implement the client on iOS device, and I deploy AsyncSocket ,

```
    [sock connectToHost:hostname onPort:SYNC_DATABASE_PORT error:&err];
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:3.0 tag:2];
```

and then, when the delegate callback:

```
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data      withTag:(long)tag
{
    NSLog(@"didReadData read data,len:%ld",(unsigned long)[data length]);
    if (tag == 2) {
        _totalReceivedLen += [data length];
        [sock readDataWithTimeout:0.5 tag:2];
        [self writeFile:data];
}
```

In this way, all data will be received, but I don't know how to determine wether the transmission have been completed?

I have tried another way like this:

```
[sock readDataToData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",EOF] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  withTimeout:-1 tag:2];
```

I supposed to end the reading when the data came to the -1 signal, but it actually doesn't work, the delegate was not called at all.
Thank you for you time, hope you can give me some advices.

Answer (score 0):

jsut add “[sock readDataToData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",EOF] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  withTimeout:-1 tag:2];” in this funchtion:

```
func onSocket(sock: AsyncSocket!, didConnectToHost host: String!, port: UInt16) {
    [sock readDataToData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",EOF] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  withTimeout:-1 tag:2]

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. The -(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port delegate is called, but the -(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag delegate is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get around with it. When I look insight the asyncSocket source code, I found that When the server finished sending the file to client, it will automatically disconnect the client.So I do the ending file job at the socketDidDisconnect delegate like this:

```
-(void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err {
if (flag > 0) {
    NSLog(@"done with sync database");
    flag = 0;
    ...
}
```

}